# Let $B=\sum_{i=1}^m A_i$, $A_i$ positive,$P$ is the projector matrix to the support of $B$,prove $PA_i=A_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Let $B=\sum_{i=1}^m A_i$ where $A_i$ are positive for $1\leq i\leq m$,and thus $B$ is also positive.Let $P$ be the projector matrix to the support of $B$,which means that if the spectral decomposition of $B=\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_ie_ie_i^t$ where $\lambda_i>0$,$Px=x$ if $x\in$ span {$e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_k$} and $Px=0$ if $x\in$ span $\{e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_k\}^\perp$. How to prove $PA_i=A_i(1\leq i\leq m)$?

Attempts:note that $PB=B$,so $\sum(P-I)A_i=0$,use the spectral decomposition of A_i and take the trace,we get $tr(P-I)A_i=0$,but not necessary $(P-I)A_i=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $0\le(I-P)A_i(I-P)\le(I-P)B(I-P)=0$ we obtain
$$
(I-P)A_i(I-P)=0.\tag{1}
$$
Therefore $A_i^{1/2}(I-P)=0$ and $(I-P)A_i=\big(A_i^{1/2}A_i^{1/2}(I-P)\big)^\ast=0$.

Alternatively, $(1)$ gives
$$
0\le(I-P)(tI+A_i)A_i(tI+A_i)(I-P)=2t(I-P)A_i^2(I-P)+(I-P)A_i^3(I-P)
$$
for every real number $t$. Since $t$ is arbitrary, $(I-P)A_i^2(I-P)$ must be zero. In turn, $A_i(I-P)=0$ and $(I-P)A_i=\big(A_i(I-P)\big)^\ast=0$.